# Excel 2010 Convert Formulas to Corresponding Text Based on ID

Tags: vba, excel

I will get right to it. I have an excel file with 2 sheets. Sheet 1 has a column that contains formulas (ie `(18299*11151)/20067`). Those numbers are IDs referencing questions stored in Sheet 2.

What I would like to do is find a way to look up those questions and place them into the formula instead of the ID numbers.

Answer (score 0):

The easy way (on a shortscale) could simply be to **Refer** each cells.

(type this in a cell and follow instructions in `{}` )

```
=({Click on sheet 2, Select the range to refer to (the ID)}*{Same thing})/{Same thing}
```

Comment: Thanks for the response. I have approx. 2700 different formulas. I dont think this would work.

Comment: @masry6683 Oh.. Then I don't know how you could transfer those "Numbers" into "Lookup machenasim". Good luck!

Answer (score 0):

If you wish to extract numbers you can simply use Left() and Right() formulas to extract a set of numbers for instance

```
=LEFT(RIGHT(A1,6),5)
```

would leave you with the **20067** but you would have to save formulas with ' sign for the Excel to seem them as text. Alternatively, you may simply make a copy of the worksheet with formulas and change their format to text, as suggested [here](http://www.extendoffice.com/documents/excel/822-excel-convert-formula-to-text-string.html).